# How to bypass dispatchOutsideContainer in mobicents tomcat container

Tags: servlets, tomcat7, sip

I am trying to get the tomcat container to direct all sip messages to my sip servlet. However if the request uri of the message is different from the host ip, the tomcat container calls  dispatchOutsideContainer() and my sip servlet never gets the message. Is there some way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your application is configured to handle the requests received at the container through the SIP Servlets Management Console at 127.0.0.1:8080/sip-servlets-management

You can read more at https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html_single/index.html#sssicar-SIP_Servlets_Server-Application-Router